# Nothing shows after login, tty1 doesn't work

Tags: gnome

I'm using gnome, gdm and ubuntu 15.10.
The gdm shows normally and I can login. However after I input the password it freezes on a blank screen with the color of gdm(that light bluish grey).
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: Also, the ubuntu splash screen isn't there. The only thing that functioned normal is gdm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself!
My current kernel is broken and that's why my graphic driver didn't load.
I went to the grub menu and logged into an older kernel, and reinstall the newest version.